# Turn date into two digits (TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str')

Tags: python, time, format

Trying to convert number of seconds into `dd:hh:mm:ss`

```
num_of_seconds = int(input("Enter number of seconds: "))

days = num_of_seconds // 86400
days = '%02d' % days
hours = (num_of_seconds - (days*86400)) // 3600
hours = '%02d' % hours
minutes = (num_of_seconds - (days*86400) - (hours*3600)) // 60
minutes = '%02d' % minutes
seconds = (num_of_seconds - (days*86400) - (hours*3600) - minutes*60)
seconds = '%02d' % seconds

print(days, ":", hours, ":", minutes, ":", seconds)
```

I want the different times to be formatted with two digits always (e.g. 05:00:00)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Move the string conversions of the variables to the end of the code.

Comment: Learn the difference between a string and an int. A string does not support mathematical operations. You should calculate with integers and then print strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following code to remove your `TypeError`:

```
seconds = 208920
seconds_in_day = 60 * 60 * 24
seconds_in_hour = 60 * 60
seconds_in_minute = 60


days = seconds // seconds_in_day
hours = (seconds - (days * seconds_in_day)) // seconds_in_hour
minutes = (seconds - (days * seconds_in_day) - (hours * seconds_in_hour)) // seconds_in_minute

left_over_seconds = seconds - days * seconds_in_day - hours * seconds_in_hour - minutes * seconds_in_minute

print(f'{days:02}', ":", f'{hours:02}', ":", f'{minutes:02}', ":", f'{left_over_seconds:02}')
```